# In the default constructor initialize attributes

Tags: java, this, enumeration, overloading, delegation

I'm kind of stuck while doing my homework and I'm having a hard time to understand what to do next. So my instructions are as follows:

> 1. Create a new class called `Card`. The Constructors from superclass check box will create a constructor stub in the code.
> 2. Create an Enumerated Type in a new source file called `Suit` with the values `NONE`, `CLUBS`, `HEARTS`, `SPADES`, `DIAMONDS`.
> 3. Create an Enumerated Type in a new source file in the same package as the `Card` class, called `Rank` with the values `JOKER`, `TWO`, `THREE`, `FOUR`, `FIVE`, `SIX`, `SEVEN`, `EIGHT`, `NINE`, `TEN`, `JACK`, `QUEEN`, `KING`, `ACE`.
> 4. In the class `Card`,
>    A) Create a class attribute (field) called `rank` of type `Rank`.
>    B) Create a class attribute (field) called `suit` of type `Suit`.
>    C) Create getters and setters for these fields. Make the setters private, since we only want the constructor to set the card `Suit` and `Rank` (we would not want a programmer or user to set more than one `ACE` of `CLUBS` for instance).
> 5. Create a constructor that accepts a `Suit` and a `Rank` and use those values to set the attributes.
> 6. In the default constructor, initialize the `suit` and `rank` attributes. Use the this constructor to call the constructor created in the previous step and initialize the rank and suit with a value of your choice (for example: `Rank.ACE`, `Suit.CLUBS`).
> 7. In the main method of the class, construct a default `Card` to demonstrate the default constructor initialization.
> 8. Also construct a few additional cards using the `Suit` and `Rank` constructor. Use local variables to hold the objects.
> 9. Using the `toString()` method from Enumerated Types, print the `Suit` and `Rank` of each `Card` created.
> 10. Create a `Deck` class that contains a field that is an array of fifty four cards (Containment).
> 11. Create a constructor on the `Deck` class that initializes the array of cards with the standard deck and two jokers, using `for` loops that iterate over the `Suit` and `Rank` values and set the array members with the appropriate `Card` constructor. Remember that the two Jokers only exist as `NONE` suits and only the Jokers use the `NONE` suit. There are many possible solutions for creating only two jokers. I used an iterator, left them out of the loop and added them in the beginning, individually. Use an `if` statement to exclude the jokers within a `for each` loop and add them before or after.
> 12. Create a `toString()` method in the `Deck` class, using another `for` loop to print all the `Card`s in the array by calling the `toString()` method on each card. This method “asks” the `Card` to print its rank and suit by only calling `toString()` on the `Card` object. There should be no reference to `Rank` or `Suit` anywhere in this method. Let `Card`'s `toString()` method do the work (Delegation).
> 13. Create a `main` method in the `Deck` class that creates a `Deck`. Then print the deck using `System.out.println()`. This will call `Deck`'s `toString()` method, which will call `toString()` on each `Card`, printing the entire deck.

```
    public class Card {

    //Default Constructor
    Card (){
    }

   //Create a class attribute (field) called rank of type Rank.
   Rank rank;
   //Create a class attribute (field) called rank of type Suit
   Suit suit;
   //Create an Enumerated Type in a new source file called Suit
   public enum Suit{
   NONE, CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS
   }
   //Create an Enumerated Type in a new source file called Rank
   public enum Rank{
   JOKER, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK,QUEEN,KING, ACE        
   }

  //Getters & Setters for Rank/Suit
 //Make the setters private, since we only want the constructor to set the   card Suit and Rank
 public Rank getRank() {
 return rank;
 }
 private void setRank(Rank rank) { 
 this.rank = rank;
 }
 public Suit getSuit() {
 return suit;
 }
 private void setSuit(Suit suit) {
 this.suit = suit;
 }

//Create a constructor that accepts a Suit and a Rank and use those values   to set the attributes.
Card ( Rank Rank, Suit Suit){ 
suit = Suit;
rank = Rank;
}






    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }



    }
```

Comment: SO doesn't work this way. Don't expect that you can just copy&paste your assignment, and your code; and that we spent our free time to read through all of that to figure where exactly you are stuck; what your problem is ... and so on. To be frank: forget about that. Describe what you tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Ok so I thought I completed up to step 4/5 correctly. I just need help understanding if I did step 5 right and someone to explain what step 6 wants me to do? I just posted to whole thing to give a better idea of as a whole what needs to be done and the steps before that I could have messed up.

Comment: Also what exactly are the getters and setters needed for?

Comment: How do I Create a constructor that accepts a Suit and a Rank and use those values to set the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is used to initialised a instance of a object. Setters are used to set the values of the variables and getters return this. Have a look at the example below,

```
public class Test {

    //private members of the instance
    private String strVariable;
    private int intVariable;

    //constructor
    //constructor sets the values of strVariable and intVariable when a Test object is intialized
    public Test(String strVariable, String intVariable) {

        this.strVariable = strVariable;
        this.intVariable = intVariable;
    }

    //setter method for setStrVariable
    //this will overwrite the value of setStrVariable that was assinged when the object was intilized
    public void setStrVariable(String strVariable) {

        this.strVariable = strVariable;
    }

    //getter for the setStrVariable
    //this will return the value of setStrVariable
    public String getStrVariable() {

        return this.strVariable;
    }
}
```